# Hidden methods and classes in java (Robotium)

Tags: java, class, robotium

Is there a way I can see how a method works?

```
public void testAddNote() throws Exception {
    solo.clickOnMenuItem("Add note");
    //Assert that NoteEditor activity is opened
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("Expected NoteEditor activity", "NoteEditor"); 
    //In text field 0, add Note 1
    solo.enterText(0, "Note 1");
    solo.goBack();
```

Is there a way I can see the source code for the `goBack()` method? `new Solo()` was declared. Is there a way I can see the Solo class? Where is it hidden?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't really have any magic.  "solo" must be declared somewhere in the class.  Eclipse should be able to find it if you ctrl-click on solo.  Perhaps some plugin is hiding it from you?  If you look at the raw .java file it HAS to be in there, probably as a member of the class you are working on--look for it near the class definition, or just do a text search in the entire file (I don't know how you are just viewing that method, but a single method is not enough to make anything work).

Once you find the type of the object "solo", you can find out about that type--worst case just google it.

Comment: And here I was thinking I was Harry Potter while coding Java.. You ruined it for me :-(

Comment: If you want magic, try out Ruby (Or Groovy if you are good at java)--it's not all gone.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on whether or not the class stored in the field solo, is in your project, or in an open source project. If it comes from a proprietary library you may not be able to see the code for it.

Java is not an interpreted language, it is a compiled language (well compiled to byte code at least). If the class comes from a jar file, you will probably need to find the source on your own on the web.

http://mvnrepository.com/

is an excellent resource for tracking down jar files, and their corresponding source-jar files.

And I'm guessing that it holds a Robotium class so you can also look here:

http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Source?tm=4

Perhaps it is this class? (or a subclass of it?)

https://github.com/jayway/robotium/blob/master/robotium-solo/src/main/java/com/jayway/android/robotium/solo/Solo.java#L691